# Both scanf("%c", x) and x=getchar aren't waiting for input

Tags: c, linux, gcc

First off, I just want to say that I hadn't heard of c 2 weeks ago, if that gives you any idea of where I am. Anyway, I was trying to write my first program that allows the user to make choices and continue in the story. Here I will just show you the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Global variables for entire program

 char proceed;  //Used to confirm that user wishes to play
 int countdwn=5;  //Used in do-while loop to count down from red value
 char xchoice; //Used in ABC  Multiple Choice Selections

int main()
{
//Introduction sequence displays a block of text for user.

    puts("\nGreetings,\n");
    puts("I am glad that you made it this far!");
    puts("Now, you will discover if it was worth your while!");
    puts("In this program you will be provided with some information");
    puts("which you must use to make wise decisions...");
    puts("Whether you survive or not remains to be seen");
    puts("But whatever your outcome, you are soley responsible");
    puts("as you are the one making the choices... for good or ill!\n\n");

//In order for the user to continue, user must type a '~' followed by enter.

    puts("Are you ready to begin!?!?");
    puts("If so press \"~\" followed by enter/return---");
    proceed=getchar();

    if(proceed!='~')
    {
            puts("\nIt seems that you don't want to continue.");
            puts("The program will now close and return you to dos");
            puts("Once the program has closed the cursor will begin to");
            puts("blink again and then type \"exit\" to exit dos");
            sleep(7);
            puts("Program Closing in 5...");

    do
    {
            printf("%d\n", countdwn);
            sleep(1);
            countdwn--;
    }
    while(countdwn>0);
    return 0;
    }

/*************************************************************************/

    puts("\nYou are living in Japan during a time known as the");
    puts("\"Sengoku Jidia,\" or age of the warring states.");
    puts("You are a Ninja --- a secret, deadly warrior.");
    puts("What kind of missions will you take on?");
    puts("What kind of dangers will you face?");
    puts("Keep going to find out!\n");
    puts("Make a selection by typing the number associated");
    puts("with the selection you wish to make, followed by hitting enter.");
    puts("Then, the next choice will automatically appear below.\n");
    puts("a. To help in the attack on an enemy castle in 1558");
    puts("b. To defend your homeland from an enemy attack in 1581");
    puts("c. To serve as a bodygard to a powerful ruler in 1600");
    puts("Make your selection a, b, or c followed by enter.");

    scanf("%c", &xchoice);

    if(xchoice=='A' || 'a')
    {
            puts("\nYou stand alone, looking up at the walls of");
            puts("Sawayama Castle near the city of Hikone.");
            puts("Activity buzzes all around you. You're a mercenary");
            puts("ninja, fighting for whomever pays you the most for your");
            puts("services. Today, you're part of an army fighting under");
            puts("Rokkaku Yoshita the samurai leader of the Rokkaku clan.");
            puts("The dodo clan is supposed be your ally, but some have");
            puts("rebelled and taken control of one of your castles.");
            puts("You have no choice but to fight to regain your loss.\n");
            puts("You are one of 50 ninjas hired to take part in the");
            puts("seige. Your leader, Doshun, is already forming plans");
            puts("on how to get inside. Doshun is a clever man and a");
            puts("respected ninja. But as night approaches, you can't");
            puts("help feeling that the time to strike is now.\n\n");
            puts("You stare at the castle wall. You know you could get");
            puts("inside. Then you could spy on the enemy or set fires");
            puts("that would drive the enemy leader, Kuranosuke from");
            puts("hiding. But Doshun is your leader. He will have a plan,");
            puts("and it might be best to find out what it is.\n\n");
            puts("a. To try to get inside the castle walls alone.");
            puts("b. To wait for Dashun's plan.");

/*****************************************************************************/

            }


    return(0);
}
```

This is all that I have written so far, but I plan to continue it with more options. You can pretty much see where it is going. The program compiles without any warnings or errors. The do-while loop with the countdown and such works fine. However, if I do press the tilde ~ key, followed by enter, instead of waiting for the user input from the

```
scanf("%c", &xchoice);
```

the program simply stops running and the terminal just goes back to displaying my current directory. (I am writing on Linux for Windows.) This is obviously not the intended outcome. Also I did try inserting a loop to make getchar work until enter is pressed and that didn't work either. I also tried using getchar to read a single character in the same way as the above scanf statement, but that had the same outcome. I am sure that I am missing something obvious... but I just can't find it. Lastly, I was wondering if there was some better way to display a lot of text on the screen besides a bunch of puts("djfasjlaksdj");

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Did you tried `scanf(" %c", &xchoice);` ?

Comment: `xchoice=='A' || 'a'` is always true. You should turn up your warning level, too, as I get a couple nice ones: *implicit declaration of function 'sleep' is invalid in C99* and *use of logical '||' with constant operand*

Comment: Why Chris? Just Curious... Is it not case sensitive? Ok, I'll try that, as there were no warnings when I did it...

Comment: In the scanf you are reading the enter that you typed before.

Comment: @ZekeLegge: You have to do `xchoice == 'A' || xchoice == 'a'`.

Comment: @ZekeLegge, `xchoice=='A'` can be true or false, `'a'` is not `'\0'`, so it's true. `__ || true` is `true`.

Comment: @Mabus, you mean with the getchar ~ situation at the top?

Comment: @ZekeLegge Yes, I mean that situation.

Comment: @chris, now I see what you mean, so that text will print every time unless I change it to xchoice=='A' || xchoice == 'a' ?

Comment: Also, you can avoid to do multiple puts. Try this: 'put("Hello "' (without single quotes) and in the next line '"world");'

Comment: I'd just like to point out that if you plan on making this game have a lot of choices, you may want to consider using some sort of tree structure, where each node in the tree represents part of the story and the children of the node are the choices you can make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your input and hit the ENTER key or After printing the Input strings, If two characters are placed in the input buffer, they are namely: the entered character and the newline character due to ENTER key. The entered character gets consumed by the `getchar()` but the newline remains in the input buffer. so the `\n` is consumed by next `scanf()`. To avoid that Try with a space before `%c`-

```
scanf(" %c", &xchoice);  // Fix 1
       ^  <-Note the space here
```

and

```
if(xchoice=='A' || 'a')
```

evaluates always true. how? You are checking your input with only `A`. Not with `a`. so if `xchoice=='A'` fails means, `'a'` remains true always. So try

```
 if(xchoice == 'A' || xchoice == 'a')) // Fix 2.
```

Comment: Although this fixes the problem, it doesn't explain why these changes are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The `getchar` function reads a single character for stdin. Unfortunately the terminal will not send any character to the program until you press enter... So this is why you need the user to type ENTER after the ~ for the `getchar` to return. However the ENTER is not read by `getchar` but gets read by the input which follows.

The best to do, since we have a line-oriented user interface, is to always read an entire line and then interpret it as a single char, a command or whatever. Best option to read a single line without running the risk to overflow is to use the `fgets` function.

**addendum.**
The suggestions to use `scanf(" %c"...)` is not good in my opinion. Image what happens if the user writes a string like "how are you?" when you ask for a single character...

Answer (score 1):

Your `getchar()` and `scanf`s reads a character and stops reading from `stdin`, but when you enter an option you send at least 2 characters: the option you typed and `\n`.  Your code reads just your option, and leaves the `\n` for the second call.

In order to avoid reading the end of line, or any other spaces or tabs, you should use `scanf(" %c", &xchoice)` (notice the space before `%c`).

And, another thing: your line:

```
if(xchoice=='A' || 'a')
```

does not work as expected.  You should change it with:

```
if(xchoice=='A' || xchoice=='a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just flush the input buffer before scanf

```
fflush(stdin);
```

good to go.